# Facebook Like button not showing up after hidden element is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am using CSS Hover to show/hide Div element with "mouseover" and "mouseout".

My problem is Fb like button does not show with "mouseover" event in Firefox and IE browser, but work done in Chrome.

I also see more the same issue but I now cannot fix yet.

Here is my CSS:

```
div#show-social, .subscribe:hover>div#div-social {
display: none;
}

.subscribe:hover>div#show-social {
display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="subscribe">
    <div id="div-social">Show is avaible</div>
    <div id="show-social">
    <!-- FB like button not Showing while Hover on this (problem with Firefox and IE) -->
       <span class="fb-like" data-href="my-URL" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is DEMO (you can test on Google Chorme. It works done. But Firefox doesn't)
http://jsfiddle.net/happi/D52j2/

How can I fix this. Thanks for all helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-render the facebook like button whenever you are showing the element (or maybe only the first time).

```
var subscribe = document.getElementsByClassName("subscribe")[0],
    showSocial = document.getElementById("show-social"),
    rendered = false;

// Wait that facebook script has been loaded
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    // FB variable is now accessible
    subscribe.onmouseover = function () {
        if (!rendered) {
            // Re-render the Facebook like button.
            FB.XFBML.parse(showSocial);
            rendered = true;
        }
    };
};
```

Edit: my code had one bug, it's getElementById and not getElementsById and I improve it as I mentioned in parenthesis, you need to render the facebook button only the first time.

Comment: Can you demo this in jsfiddle? I dont know how to add. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/happi/D52j2/)